# In a Rails view, how iterate a group of objects that should display as rows of 4 for instance?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Right now I am using the modulus operator and doing something like this:
The purpose is just to close the previous and create a new "row-fluid" div after every fourth item in the array/result

```
<div class="row-fluid">
  <% Group.all.each_with_index do |g, index| %>
    <% if index != 0 && index % 4 == 0 %> </div> <br> <div class="row-fluid"> <% end %>
    <div class="col-lg-3" id="my_group_tile_<%= g.id %>">
      <div class="tiletop">
        <div class="span12">
         <%= cl_image_tag(g.avatar, :crop => :pad, :height => 200, :width => 250, :class => "tile-image") %>
         </div>
        <h4 id="tileheader"> 
          <a href="/groups/<%= g.id %>"><%= g.title %> &nbsp; </a>  
        </h4>
      </div>
    <div class="tile-info">
      <%= truncate(g.info, :length => 100, :omission => '... (continued)') %>
    </div>    
    <hr>
    <span id="group_members_count_<%= g.id %>">    
      <span class="badge badge-black" style="color:white">
        <%= g.members.count %> members
      </span> 
    </span>
    <span id="join_<%= g.id %>" class="btn-wrapper">
      <%= render :partial => 'join_button', :locals => { :group => g } %>
    </span>
  </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

**UPDATE**: after using the accepted answer things are quite a bit cleaner.

```
<% Group.all.each_slice(4) do |slice_of_four| %>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="bs-example">
      <div class="row">
        <% slice_of_four.each do |g| %>
          <div class="col-lg-3" id="my_group_tile_<%= g.id %>">
            <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
              <%= cl_image_tag(g.avatar, :crop => :pad, :height => 180, :width => 266, :class => "tile-image") %>
            </a>
          </div>
        <% end %>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>  
<% end %>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using each_slice enumerator
http://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/each_slice

```
Group.all.each_slice(4) do |slice_of_four|
   *now you can do your operations on the slices of four*
end
```

and try not using Group.all it will get all the groups in memory and if the the groups table is big you will have unneccesary problems

Comment: That looks good. Any suggestions on how to be more efficient while loading the groups for pagination?

Comment: actually a lot of options you have , if you use https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate  , this will solve both the problems for you(memory + slicing)
or without the gem , you can just load the records 4 at a time by using .limit(4), but both of these will be overkill.
Instead i will suggest use http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Batches.html  find_each (try out different options they have)

Comment: I implemented your each_slice suggestion and it's SO much cleaner. I am not dealing with a large number of groups at this point but the batches docs did seem interesting. Thanks.